# Filemaker Cost Remaining input field

Tags: database, filemaker

I have three to more vendor one can be paid and others may not be paid. so if the vendor is paid he will check a check box(X) near to the amount box. The check box datatype is text. i want to put a calculation that should exclude the vendor paid and should calculate the remaining amount. This is how i implemented.

```
If(
   (IsEmpty ( Vendor Paid )); 0;
   Sum(Invoices::Cost Total)
)
```

Here the Vendor Paid is the column name and Cost Total is the sum of all the vendors including the paid one.

```
Cost Total=  Sum ( Invoice Line Items::Actual_Extended Cost )
```

Comment: Please explain what tables you have and what are the relationships between them. Otherwise this makes very little sense. Can different items of the same invoice have different vendors? If not, in which table is the checkbox? Also, why don't you record some actual details about the payment (e.g. date, amount)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your database structure properly, you have three tables `Vendors`, `Invoices` and `Invoice Line Items`. Your `Invoice Line Items` table has a field `Cost` on it. Your `Invoices` table has a flag (field) `Vendor Paid` on it. And on the `Vendors` table you'd like a sum of the total cost and a sum of the unpaid cost.

These fields are related in one-to-many relationships as follows:

```
Vendors --< Invoices --< Invoice Line Items
```

Here's one method:

#### Invoices Table

On your `Invoices` table create a calculation field `Invoice Total`, which is the sum of all costs. The code for which is:

```
Sum ( Invoice Line Items::Cost )
```

Additionally on your `Invoices` table create a calculation field `Invoice Total Unpaid`, which is the cost if your `Vendor Paid` field is not checked:

```
If (
    IsEmpty ( Vendor Paid ) ; 0 ;
    Invoice Total
)
```

#### Vendors Table

Now on your `Vendors` table you can create your `Cost Total` calculation field, the sum of all costs:

```
Sum ( Invoices::Invoice Total )
```

And a `Cost Total Unpaid` calculation field, the sum of all unpaid costs:

```
Sum ( Invoices::Invoice Total Unpaid )
```